# Partial Derivative in Infinitesimal transformation: $\phi \rightarrow \phi_{\lambda} = \phi(x + \lambda, t)$,

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem

Given the Lagrangian:
$$
\textit{L} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{v^2} \left( \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right)^2  - \left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\right)^2 \right) - \frac{1}{2} \alpha(T -T_o)\phi^2 - \frac{1}{4}\beta\phi⁴
$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are postive constants.

and the continuous transformation $\phi \rightarrow \phi_{\lambda} = \phi(x + \lambda, t)$,my professor stated that

$$
\partial_{\lambda} \left( \frac{\partial \phi_{\lambda}}{dx} \right) \Bigr|_{\substack{\lambda=0}} = 0
$$

I don't understand why it is equal to zero. Could someone explain why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide some more context for this? On its face, this statement seems false in general, so perhaps there was a misunderstanding of what your instructor meant.

Comment: Is your $\partial_\lambda = \partial/\partial \lambda$?  If so, why did you define $\delta\phi$ which is not used anywhere?

Comment: @garyp you are right, it was no need

Comment: @J.Murray I edited my question again. What do you think?
Thanks a lot for your atention

Comment: should it be $\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)^2$ in the middle? Anyway, what's the purpose of introducing the Lagrangian? I still can't think of any possible interpretation under which the variation of $\phi$ wrt $\lambda$ is $0$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo my professor stated that the kinetic terms are invariant for this transformation, which I do not understand

Comment: you should ask your professor what they meant. as of now the only thing I can say is that if you define $f(\lambda,x,t)=\phi_{\lambda}(x,t)=\phi(x+\lambda,t)$ then $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \lambda\partial x}\bigg|_{(0,x,t)}=\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}\bigg|_{(x,t)}$

Comment: @peek-a-boo  I will . thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

That's very false. Even in a very special case where for example $\phi(x,t)=x^2$, we have $\phi_{\lambda}(x,t)=\phi(\lambda+x,t)=(x+\lambda)^2$, so taking the partial with respect to $x$ then $\lambda$ and setting $\lambda=0$ yields $2$, which is non-zero.

Comment: I have the same idea, that’s the reason I coulda understand it